# Python Kivymd - AttributeError object has no attribute

Tags: python, kivymd

Not sure where I'm going wrong, When changing the value of MDSlider it should update a label but I receive the error

the `kv` is loaded as a string within my `py` file, if I test out the slider by simply printing the value to the console it works. but when I try to update a label get the following error??

```
AttributeError: 'Level' object has no attribute 'training_level'
```

here's my code

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = """
ScreenManager:
    Profile:
    Level:
    Routine:
    Start:

     
    
    
<Profile>:
    name: "Profile"
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (1,1,1,1)
        Rectangle:
            source: "bg.jpg"
            size: root.width, root.height
            pos: self.pos    

    MDLabel:
        text: "Select a Profile"
        font_size: "32"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .95}  
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: "Guest"
        font_size: "32" 
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}  
        on_release: app.root.current = "Level" 

    MDBottomAppBar:
        MDToolbar:
            title: "HIIT"
            icon: "account-cog"
            type: "bottom"
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: x]]
            mode: "center"

<Level>:
    name: "Level"
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (1,1,1,1)
        Rectangle:
            source: "bg.jpg"
            size: root.width, root.height
            pos: self.pos
    
    MDLabel:
        text: "What is your Level of training?"
        font_size: "32"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .95}

    MDLabel:
        id: "training_level"
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
        text_color: 1,1,1,1
        halign: "center"
        text: "2"
        font_size: "128"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .65}
 
    MDSlider:
        min: 1
        max: 3
        value: 2
        size: 500, 50
        size_hint: None, None
        hint: False
        step: 1
        orientation: "horizontal"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .40}    
        on_value: root.change_height(*args)
                
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: "Next"
        font_size: "32"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .92, "center_y": .18}     
        on_release: app.root.current = "Routine"   
    
    MDBottomAppBar:
        MDToolbar:
            title: "HIIT"
            icon: "account-cog"
            type: "bottom"
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: x]]
            mode: "center"    

<Routine>:
    name: "Routine"
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (1,1,1,1)
        Rectangle:
            source: "bg.jpg"
            size: root.width, root.height
            pos: self.pos

    MDLabel:
        text: "Select a Routine"
        font_size: "32"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .95}
     
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: "10 Minute Beginner"
        font_size: "32"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}     
        on_release: app.root.current = "Start"   
                
    MDBottomAppBar:
        MDToolbar:
            title: "HIIT"
            icon: "account-cog"
            type: "bottom"
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: x]]
            mode: "center"                

<Start>:
    name: "Start"
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (1,1,1,1)
        Rectangle:
            source: "bg.jpg"
            size: root.width, root.height
            pos: self.pos
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: "Stop"
        font_size: "32"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}     
        on_release: app.root.current = "Profile"   
    MDBottomAppBar:
        MDToolbar:
            title: "HIIT"
            icon: "account-cog"
            type: "bottom"
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: x]]
            mode: "center"                
"""

class Profile(MDScreen):
    pass

class Level(MDScreen):
    def change_height(self, *args):
        #print(str(round(args[1],1)))
        self.training_level.text = str(round(args[1],1))
    pass 

class Routine(MDScreen):
    pass

class Start(MDScreen):
    pass

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Blue"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

MainApp().run()
```

Comment: I think that' because `self.training_level` is not defined anywhere in `Level`'s methods. You probably should initialize it as an `MDLabel` object first

Comment: I'm completely new to this so please forgive my ignorance, I was under the impression that adding the ID to the MDLabel in the kv string would make it accessible and it worked prior to adding screenmanager and kivymd. Not sure how to do what your saying ??

Comment: I notice you're trying to access and change the text of the `MDLabel` object whose ID is `"training_level"`. I think instead of using `self.training_level.text = str(round(args[1],1))`, you should try `self.ids['"training_level"'].text = str(round(args[1], 1))` instead. Let me know if you still encounters any issues